# ArcGIS for Server cached map service - jumbled tiles issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, tiles, cache

Using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3.1 and ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1, I am trying to create a cached map service. It includes a raster image (that i've added to a mosaic dataset) and a few vector layers. I used the default ArcGIS Online tile structure.

When trying to view the publish service via the Javascript API viewer (that we have locally hosted), I have a jumble of map tiles that differ depending on the scale zoomed to.

[image]

My ideas on what may have gone wrong:
- Mosaic dataset contains only one raster image. I added it to a gdb because it was originally ECW format and server did not like this.
- Tile structure chosen is not correct